# Transformers: How to use CUDA for inferencing?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, inference

I have fine-tuned my models with GPU but inferencing process is very slow, I think this is because inferencing uses CPU by default. Here is my inferencing code:

```
txt = "This was nice place"
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_path, num_labels=24)
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1')
encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, add_special_tokens = True, truncation = True, padding = "max_length", return_attention_mask = True, return_tensors = "pt")
output = model(**encoding)
output = output.logits.softmax(dim=-1).detach().cpu().flatten().numpy().tolist()
```

Here is my second inferencing code, which is using pipeline (for different model):

```
classifier = transformers.pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
result = classifier(txt)
```

How can I force transformers library to do faster inferencing on GPU? I have tried adding `model.to(torch.device("cuda"))` but that throws error:

```
Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu
```

I suppose the problem is related to the data not being sent to GPU. There is a similar issue here: [pytorch summary fails with huggingface model II: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585678/pytorch-summary-fails-with-huggingface-model-ii-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-t)

How would I send data to GPU with and without pipeline? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you tried `model.to(torch.device("cuda"))`, at the very least it should return you an error as your data doesn't seem to belong to the same device.

Comment: It was in wrong part of the code, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should transfer your input to CUDA as well *before* performing the inference:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')

# transfer model
model.to(device)

# define input and transfer to device
encoding = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, 
     add_special_tokens=True, 
     truncation=True, 
     padding="max_length", 
     return_attention_mask=True, 
     return_tensors="pt")

encoding = encoding.to(device)

# inference
output = model(**encoding)
```

Be aware [`nn.Module.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to) is in-place, while [`torch.Tensor.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.to.html) is not (it does a copy!).

Comment: Oh thank you! Can I do something like `result = classifier(txt).to(device)` in order to do same with pipeline?

Comment: Since `classifier ` is a model, then `classifier.to(device)` should work.

Answer (score 5):

#### For the pipeline code question

The problem is the default behavior of `transformers.pipeline` to use CPU. But from [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2704#issuecomment-1016971649) you can add the `device=0` parameter to use the 1st GPU, for example.

- `device=0` to utilize GPU cuda:0
- `device=1` to utilize GPU cuda:1

```
pipeline = pipeline(TASK, model=MODEL_PATH, device=0)
```

Your code becomes:

```
classifier = transformers.pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english", device=0)
result = classifier(txt)
```